# Razor Template C# Exception thrown: 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' in RazorEngine.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I am trying to create a template in my C# project using Razor Engine. The template should be populated from value that I get from the database.
The template looks like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>  Tier : </td>  
        <td> @Model.tier</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  Author : </td>
        <td> @Model.author</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>  Quotation For : </td>
        <td> @Model.quotationFor</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The backend code looks like

```
 var model = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
 for (int i=0;i<value.Count;i++) {
      model.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name[i], value[i]));
 }
 var template = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Templates/dataDump.html"));
 var body = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

The model list consists of values that I fetch from the DB. I want to populate the template using this model but I get this error

```
Exception thrown: 'RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' in RazorEngine.dll
```

Comment: I followed this blog to solve http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-basics-generating-your-first-email/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to pass a very complex model which you did not define well in your template

It should be like this.

```
  var body =  Razor.Parse(template, new {tier = "tier", author="author",quotationFor=".quotationFor"});
```

If you want to make it dynamic like you showed

```
var model = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
```

you would have to modify your template

```
<table>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Key </td>  
        <td>@item.Value</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: the above works but it is hard coded. I need the list to be dynamic so something like new { name[i] = value[i], name[i+1] = value[i+1]..} How do   I create such a model?